EF Core 6.0 with PostgreSQL: date query not returning results despite data being present
I'm working on an ASP.NET Core 6.0 project using Entity Framework Core with PostgreSQL. I'm trying to query a table based on a DateTime column, but I am not getting any results, even though the data exists in the table.
Here's my code:
public int GetDailyEarning(DateTime date)
{
    var operationQuery = _operationReadRepository.GetWhere(o => o.OperationDate.Date == date.Date);
    var operationDetails = _operationDetailReadRepository.GetWhere(od =>
        operationQuery.Any(o => o.Id == od.OperationId)).ToList();

    var dailyEarning = operationDetails.Sum(od => (double?)od.PaymentAmount) ?? 0.0;
    return Convert.ToInt32(dailyEarning);
}


OperationDate is a timestamp without time zone in PostgreSQL
The date parameter in GetDailyEarning method is passed as a DateTime

The problem is that operationQuery returns no results, even though the table contains entries with the exact same date (2024-08-14 00:00:00).
What I've tried

I verified that the data exists in the table by querying the database directly with a SQL query
I ensured that the OperationDate column is set to timestamp without time zone in PostgreSQL
I tried comparing the dates using various approaches (like date.Date, EF.Functions.DateDiffDay, etc.), but none of them worked
There are no exceptions or errors being thrown; the query simply returns no results

My environment

.NET 6.0
Entity Framework Core
PostgreSQL

Question
Why is my query returning no results when querying by date, and how can I fix this issue? Is there something specific about PostgreSQL or EF Core that I might be missing?

Additional to the things to check in my answer, are you using the Pomelo EF provider for PostreSQL? (Recommended, if not)

Probably the best thing is to hook up a trace to look at the SQL generated by EF. When debugging with a .Net Core console app I EF Core automatically outputs SQL statements to console in Debug builds when using services.AddDbContext<TDbContext>(). If registering a DbContextFactory etc. with other IoC containers, you can add the console output using the OptionBuilder. optionsBuilder.LogTo(Console.WriteLine) Otherwise you can use a trace tool on the database itself. You might find that EF is interpreting the parameter as a local datetime converting to UTC, or vice versa. The expression o.OperationDate.Date == date.Date looks sus. Any expression you pass must translate cleanly down to SQL. Your repository may not be passing that through as Linq-to-Entity (would be revealed in the SQL) or garbling one or both values. If the entity's data type for the OperationDate is "DateTime" and it is stored in the database as the date value, I wouldn't use the .Date on it, just o.OperationDate == date.Date.
If you copy the SQL and run it on your DB and it returns the expected data, check the connection string at runtime /w var connectionString = _context.Database.GetConnectionString(); and verify that is going to the database you expect it to. (A surprisingly common issue!)
The last thing to check would be to eliminate anything your Repository pattern might be causing. Try a basic Linq-to-Entity against the DbContext directly. If that works, scrap, or spend the time to work out why the Repository is mucking things up. EF already provides a Unit of Work and Repository in the form of the DbContext and DbSet respectively. Further abstracting those adds complexity, sacrifices performance/flexibility, and can be responsible for issues that would otherwise be avoided with a simpler native solution.
